# Unable to updating an array inside list's map function. Scala Programming

Tags: arrays, scala, list, maps

I am trying to update an `Array[Array[String]]` type when a map function is called on list.

```
var m : Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(""))
var n : List((String, Double))
n contains 100 elements
i want to update m foreach element in n like
n.map(x => {
   m :+ Array("a","b","c");
   x
})
```

but I am ending up with empty array. Values are not appending to m.
I want to try it for an `RDD` as well.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It'd be nice to ask atomic questions with a better formatted code, that way people can help you better. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for formatting help. I would drop the part on Spark first and ask it later as a separate question if needed. Are you familiar with mutability and immutability concepts and how `Array`s and `Lists` are different in Scala?

Comment: Hi Nader Ghanbari. Thanks for the information provided. I am aware of those concepts of Scala

Answer (score 1):

First, the idea of `map` is to transform the collection on which map is being called, not mutating other collection - `foreach` would be better.

Second, the reason why you end up with an empty array is because `:+`  creates a copy with the element added, it does not mutate the original array - [*scaladoc*](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html#:+(elem:A):Array[A]).

Third, arrays aren't the best collections for incremental building, because is not efficient to resize them, you can create a big array first and then updating every position by index *(however, that would be very imperative)*, or you could use an `ArrayBuffer` [*scaladoc*](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayBuffer.html), or you could map the list and end up with a `List[Array[A]]` or a `List[List[A]]` *(that would be the most functional way of doing it)*.

Fourth, what exactly you mean with trying it with and `RDD` as well... if you want to build an array by iterating a RDD, that's conceptually wrong. Or, if you want to build a RDD by iterating a List, that's conceptually wrong too.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I need to create a collection of items for every iteration of a transformation and that collection is global to the application, shared by other transformations. A sequence of transformations will update the collection for every iteration on an RDD. Can I use another RDD as the global collection? How can I achieve this solution?

Comment: I get it when you’re saying, conceptually wrong. But is there any other good approach for that problem?

Comment: @karteekkadari, without some context is hard to tell what could be a good solution. Also, the reason why I think it is conceptually wrong is that, if you want to update elements on a global array by _"iterating"_ an RDD, then I'm assuming you have a correspondence of 1 to 1 on the number of elements, but that means your driver must have enough memory to hold a local array with the same number of elements than a **Distributed Dataset** that has to be splitted across the RAM of **many machines** - that doesn't make sense, so probably a RDD would be better...

Comment: ...but, again you can't create a RDD by _appending/prepending/adding_ elements one by one, but instead they are intended to be created as the result of a transformation on another RDD. The problem is that your description of what you need is too abstract, so I'm not sure what could be a good solution for it.

Comment: That make sense. Sometimes it’s difficult to think broader. For my case, eventually, the collection is of small size. Anyway, I want to try accumulatorsv2 for this. Thanks for your concern